# Get XML node from SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am trying to get to a node in XML using SQL Server.

```
CREATE TABLE temp.testXML(ID INT, xmlinput XML NULL);

INSERT INTO temp.testXML 
VALUES (1, '<root><node1><lang>English</lang></node1><innernode><info>20170117T022113</info></innernode></root>')
```

I want to print "info" node i.e "20170117T022113"

```
SELECT 
    t.id,
    x.XmlCol.value('(/innernode/info)[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS dt
FROM 
    [temp].[testxml] as t
CROSS APPLY 
    t.rawxml.nodes('/root') as x(XmlCol)
```

I am getting a null.

How can I get to the node value??

Thanks
MR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two mistakes in your query

- Use `xmlinput` column name in `nodes` function instead `rawxml`
- Remove the first `/` in value function

Query

```
SELECT t.id,
       x.XmlCol.value('(innernode/info)[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS dt
FROM   [testxml] AS t
       CROSS APPLY t.xmlinput.nodes('/root') AS x(XmlCol)
```

Comment: I had one more clarification, when do you use '/' and when don't you use. Thanks so much

Comment: @user2726975 - Am not a expert in xml but I have seen in `value` method start with `/` when `XQuery`(first parameter)  starts with `root`. Something like `value('(/root/innernode/info)[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)' ) `

Comment: @user2726975 But in simple words: 1-slash = *move one level down*, 2-slashes=*find any node below*, no slash = *relative to the context node*. You start to *navigate* at the root, than you *move* down (and up/to the side) the path. The current *position* is the *context node*. Any path starts from there. In the very beginning the root node is the context node. Here you'll find a [comprehensive overview](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2142-using-and-expressions-in-xpath-xml-search-directives-in-coldfusion.htm)

Comment: @Shnugo - Thanks.. TBH it was helpful to me in understanding